# how to create three-level donut chart in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image: here is the image for three-level donut chart]

I'm using trying to create a multi-level donut chart in d3 version5
This image is drawn by d3 version3. it is working fine in version3. I decided to upgrade d3 to the latest version. now, donut chart is not drawn by d3(also no errors in the console)

**D3 version 3 > version 5**

---

Here is the sample dataset I used:

**Hint:** *first value* in the array is **used storage** and *second* is **free storage**

```
 {
    average: [30.012, 69.988],
    minimum: [10, 90],
    maximum: [40, 60]
}
```

**Note:** Above data is just a sample this is not exact data.

Here is the *code* I tried:

```
var width = 300;
var height = 300;
var radius = Math.floor((width / 6) - 2);

var classFn = function(a, b) {
    return a === 0 ? classes[b] : 'default';
};

var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null);
var arc = d3.svg.arc();

var svg = d3.select(selector).append("svg");
svg.attr("width", width);
svg.attr("height", height);
svg = svg.append("g");
svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var gs = svg.selectAll("g").data(d3.values(dataset)).enter().append("g");
var path = gs.selectAll("path");
path = path.data(function(d) {
    return pie(d);
});
path.enter().append("path");
path.attr("class", function(d, i, j) {
    return classFn(i, j);
})
path.attr("d", function(d, i, j) {
    return arc.innerRadius((j === 0 ? 0 : 2) + radius * j).outerRadius(radius * (j + 1))(d);
});
```

**Note:** This code is working fine in **d3 version3**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**2. Update**:

I've updated the answer with a better solution. I didn't do this at first, because I didn't grasp you structure. I've updated it to being more D3 idiomatic. Plus it does away with the hack I made in my first update :)

```
    var dataset = {
      average: [0, 100],
      minimum: [0, 100],
      maximum: [0, 100]
    }

    var width = 300;
    var height = 300;
    var radius = Math.floor((width / 6) - 2);

    var pie = d3.pie().sort(null);
    var arc = d3.arc();

    var svg = d3.select('body').append("svg");
    svg.attr("width", width);
    svg.attr("height", height);
    svg = svg.append("g");
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var gs = svg.selectAll("g").data(d3.values(dataset)).enter().append("g");

    gs.each(function (d, j) {
      d3.select(this).selectAll('path')
        .data(pie(d)).enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr("class", function(d, i) {
          // return classFn(i);
        })
        .attr('d', function (d) {
          return arc
            .innerRadius((j === 0 ? 0 : 2) + radius * j)
            .outerRadius(radius * (j + 1))(d);
        })
    })
```

The updated code uses the index (here `j`) that is available when appending the `g` elements, which corresponds to you original `j` index. This makes it possible to calculate the radii in the original way.
To achieve this, the arc appending code is wrapped into a `.each` function that iterates over the `g` elements, making `j` available to us.

The class application should work as well, but I've commented it out, as the `classFn` function doesn't work, since the `classes` variable is not present.

**1. Update**:

Besides the original answer, when calculating the arc radii you rely on a `j` value that is different from D3 v3 and v5. I summise that `j` is used the index of the `d3.values` array, so I've cooked up a way to reverse look-up that index based on the input values.

First create a map for reverse mapping data values into their corresponding index:

```
var dataValueJoinChar = '¤'
var datasetValuesToIndex = d3.values(dataset).reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
  acc[`0${dataValueJoinChar}${curr[0]}`] = i
  acc[`1${dataValueJoinChar}${curr[1]}`] = i
  return acc
}, {})
```

Then change the last part of your code to:

```
path = path.data(function(d) {
  return pie(d);
}).enter().append("path");

path.attr("class", function(d, i, j) {
  return classFn(i, j);
})

path.attr("d", function(d, i, j) {
  var orgIndex = datasetValuesToIndex[`${i}${dataValueJoinChar}${d.data}`]
  return arc
    .innerRadius((orgIndex === 0 ? 0 : 2) + radius * orgIndex)
    .outerRadius(radius * (orgIndex + 1))(d);
});
```

It might not be too pretty, but it's a simple adaption of your code that works.

------- **Original answer** --------

In D3 v5 pie and arc are found at `d3.pie` and `d3.arc` respectively. Therefore, try changing:

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null);
var arc = d3.svg.arc();
```

To this instead:

```
var pie = d3.pie().sort(null);
var arc = d3.arc();
```

Pie API reference: https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/v1.3.4/README.md#pie

Arc API reference: https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/v1.3.4/README.md#arc

If you use a bundler to bundle sub-modules, both are part of the `d3-shape` module. If not they are both available in the full D3 library.

Hope this helps!

Comment: it is creating problem when all the data is 0 in used

Comment: It's a bit of a hack, really. When calculating the inner and outer radii of the arcs, you're using the index in the position of the array pairs in the `dataset` to determine which level, the arcs should be. That is the `j` value in your code. That value is no longer available in D3 v5, so we create it ourselves by mapping the in-value index (0 or 1) and the corresponding data value to the original outer index. This we have enough information to look up when calculating the radius, enabling us to calculate what at what level the arc should be.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'when all the data is 0 in used'. Can you elaborate? Perhaps you can make a JSFiddle showcasing it? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: `{
    average: [0, 100],
    minimum: [0, 100],
    maximum: [0, 100]
}` in this case

Comment: also i'm trying apply same colors it is not working

Comment: Right, that was an error. I've updated the answer with a sleeker example. The colouring should work, but I can't test it since the `classes` variable is not available.